# How can I change the v-alert inner text/html?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I use `vuetify` and `vue-property-decorator` for display an alert:

```
<v-alert dismissible :value="true" color="error" icon="new_releases">
  some text.. some text.. <a @click="changeTheAlertMessage">click me</a>.
</v-alert>
```

How I change the inner text/html by clicking on the a-button?

```
@Component({})
export default class SomeView extends Vue {
  changeTheAlertMessage() {
    //here: How I access to alert instance???
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a [working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pOMZwR).

The approach used is the following:

1. model the text you will like to change as a reactive data variable;
2. define a method, named `changeTheAlertMessage()`, aimed to change the text according to your needs.

I mean like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      messageToChange: "Original text"
    }
  },

  methods: {
    changeTheAlertMessage: function(event) {
     this.messageToChange = "New text"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: how about to change the content inside v-alert tag?
`  some text.. some text.. <a @click="changeTheAlertMessage">click me</a>.`

Comment: Is the content you're expecting just text or another dom element?